# asp.net 2015 mvc url route

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I'm a beginner in asp.net tech and c#. I was following a tutorial about building a storefront using mvc 3 this is the link http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-1. the application was running ok with the exception of some pages won't load. these pages are the detail page and the create page for the admin. I have two controllers name `storecontroller` and `storemanagercontroller`. I added one controller for account because I can't access the web configuration manager for asp.net. my questions are; did the additional controller mess with the other controller url route, because its not part of the tutorial? or I'm following the wrong tutorial because I'm using a different version of MVC?

This are the code for the Storecontrollers:

```
namespace loginApplication.Controllers
{
 public class StoreController : Controller
  {
    loginApplicationEntities storeDB = new loginApplicationEntities();
    //
    // GET: /Store/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var genres = storeDB.Genres.ToList();
        return View(genres);
    }

    public ActionResult Browse(string genre)
    {
        var genreModel = storeDB.Genres.Include("Albums")
    .Single(g => g.Name == genre);

        return View(genreModel);
    }
    public ActionResult Detail(int id)
    {
        var album = storeDB.Albums.Find(id);

        return View(album);
    }
 }
}
```

this is the code for the storemanagercontroller

```
namespace loginApplication.Controllers
{
    public class StoreManagerController : Controller
     {
      private loginApplicationEntities db = new  loginApplicationEntities();

    // GET: /StoreManager/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
         var albums = db.Albums.Include(a => a.Artist).Include(a => a.Genre);
        return View(albums.ToList());
    }

      // GET: /StoreManager/Details/5
      public ActionResult Details(int? id)
      {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Album album = db.Albums.Find(id);
        if (album == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(album);
    }

    // GET: /StoreManager/Create
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.ArtistId = new SelectList(db.Artists, "ArtistId", "Name");
        ViewBag.GenreId = new SelectList(db.Genres, "GenreId", "Name");
        return View();
    }

    // POST: /StoreManager/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="AlbumId,GenreId,ArtistId,Title,Price,AlbumArtUrl")] Album album)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Albums.Add(album);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.ArtistId = new SelectList(db.Artists, "ArtistId", "Name", album.ArtistId);
        ViewBag.GenreId = new SelectList(db.Genres, "GenreId", "Name", album.GenreId);
        return View(album);
    }

    // GET: /StoreManager/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        Session["AlbumId"] = id;//new
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Album album = db.Albums.Find(id);
        if (album == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        ViewBag.ArtistId = new SelectList(db.Artists, "ArtistId", "Name", album.ArtistId);
        ViewBag.GenreId = new SelectList(db.Genres, "GenreId", "Name", album.GenreId);
        return View(album);
    }

    // POST: /StoreManager/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include="AlbumId,GenreId,ArtistId,Title,Price,AlbumArtUrl")] Album album)
    {
        album.AlbumId = (int)Session["AlbumId"];//new
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(album).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.ArtistId = new SelectList(db.Artists, "ArtistId", "Name", album.ArtistId);
        ViewBag.GenreId = new SelectList(db.Genres, "GenreId", "Name", album.GenreId);
        return View(album);
    }

    // GET: /StoreManager/Delete/5
    public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Album album = db.Albums.Find(id);
        if (album == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(album);
    }

    // POST: /StoreManager/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        Album album = db.Albums.Find(id);
        db.Albums.Remove(album);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
}
```

this is my global.asx

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(
        new loginApplication.Models.SampleData());
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}
```

this is the routeconfig.cs on App_Start

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Root",
            url: " ",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tutorial is good, MVC 3-5 are very similar (not vNext!)

I don't know what you are attempting to do with

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Root",
        url: " ",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

If I suppose well you can delete it, you can access your actions in urls you can find in comments

```
/StoreManager/Edit/5
/Store/Details/5
```

Be more accurate in your question and ask what is not working or what you don't know how to do.

Comment: i delete it but still i could not access the pages. yes those are the pages i m attempting to access, and it still shows server error on them. is there anything that i missed or should do to correct this problem?